# Debo cambiar el color y el contenido de mi botón cuando de clic, el problema es que no se como

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  
  $('#apagado').click(function(){
    alert("entro");
    var colorClase = $('#apagado').text();

   if(colorClase ='apagado'){
         $('#apagado').addClass('btn btn-primary');
  }
  else{
     $('#apagado').removeClass('btn btn-danger');  
  }
                      
           
});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
    Deber No 1
  </title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

}
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
<div class="page-header">
<h1>EXAMEN DE PROGRAMACI&Oacute;N WEB II, PERIODO P39 </h1>
</div>
 <div>
  <form>
 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
  <button id="apagado" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> APAGADO </button>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
 <button id="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> ELIMINAR </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id = "error-message"> 
  </div>
   </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
   <p>UNIVERSIDAD METROPOLITANA</p>
  </div>
   </div>
  
   </form>

 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifique tu código para usar un poco más de JQuery:

`toggleClass` te permite alternar entre varias clases.

`hasClass` verifica si el elemento tiene una clase determinada.

Al HTML solo le quite un } que tenía de más.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('#apagado').click(function(){
    //alert("entro");
    
    // Alternamos la clase, esto hace que cambie el color
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary btn-danger');
    
    // Definimos el texto según la clase seleccionada
    if( $(this).hasClass('btn-primary') ) $(this).text("Encendido");
    if( $(this).hasClass('btn-danger') ) $(this).text("Apagado");
    
});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
    Deber No 1
  </title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
<div class="page-header">
<h1>EXAMEN DE PROGRAMACI&Oacute;N WEB II, PERIODO P39 </h1>
</div>
 <div>
  <form>
 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
  <button id="apagado" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> APAGADO </button>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
 <button id="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> ELIMINAR </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id = "error-message"> 
  </div>
   </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
   <p>UNIVERSIDAD METROPOLITANA</p>
  </div>
   </div>
  
   </form>

 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigos me sirvió de mucho

Answer (score 0):

Intenta averiguando si el boton tiene la clase `btn-danger` entonces cambias a la clase `btn-primary` y viseversa con el metodo `.hasClass()` de jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  
  $('#apagado').click(function(){
     var $btn = $(this);
    if($btn.hasClass("btn-primary"))
    {
      $btn.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger");
      $btn.text("APAGADO");
    }
    else{
      $btn.removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-primary");
       $btn.text("ENCENDIDO");
    }                              
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
    Deber No 1
  </title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

}
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
<div class="page-header">
<h1>EXAMEN DE PROGRAMACI&Oacute;N WEB II, PERIODO P39 </h1>
</div>
 <div>
  <form>
 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
  <button id="apagado" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> APAGADO </button>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
 <button id="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> ELIMINAR </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id = "error-message"> 
  </div>
   </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
   <p>UNIVERSIDAD METROPOLITANA</p>
  </div>
   </div>
  
   </form>

 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El codigo se puede simplificar utilizando un [operador ternario](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_ternario) de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  
  $('#apagado').click(function(){
     var $btn = $(this);
    $btn.hasClass("btn-primary") ?
      $btn.removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-danger").text("APAGADO")
      :  $btn.removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-primary").text("ENCENDIDO");
    
    
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>
    Deber No 1
  </title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

}
</head>
<body>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
<div class="page-header">
<h1>EXAMEN DE PROGRAMACI&Oacute;N WEB II, PERIODO P39 </h1>
</div>
 <div>
  <form>
 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
  <button id="apagado" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> APAGADO </button>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
 <button id="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> ELIMINAR </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id = "error-message"> 
  </div>
   </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
   <p>UNIVERSIDAD METROPOLITANA</p>
  </div>
   </div>
  
   </form>

 </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar ToggleClass, por ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $('#apagado').click(function(){
        var $btn = $(this);
        $btn.toggleClass('btn-primary')
        $btn.text($btn.hasClass("btn-primary") ? "ENCENDIDO" : "APAGADO");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas cuando comparas.

El primero es que en el HTML el valor del botón está en mayúsculas y tu comparas en minúsculas:

```
if (colorClase = 'apagado') {
```

El segundo es que usas un sólo signo de igualdad para comparar, si colocas dos funcionará.

De todos modos, puedes usar [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) para alternar entre clases.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#apagado').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-danger btn-primary');
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'APAGADO' ? 'ENCENDIDO' : 'APAGADO');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>
    Deber No 1
  </title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="estilo.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  }
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>EXAMEN DE PROGRAMACI&Oacute;N WEB II, PERIODO P39 </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button id="apagado" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">APAGADO</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <button id="eliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"> ELIMINAR </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12" id="error-message">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>UNIVERSIDAD METROPOLITANA</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Cedano, siendo que el elemento de tipo 'button' está definido con la clase 'btn-danger' creo que es innecesario incluirlo como parte del argumento de toggleClass, basta alternar únicamente por la clase 'btn-primary' , es decir: $(this).toggleClass('btn-primary');